Error "process is not defined" when importing { Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';
I have error when import @metaplex-foundation/js lib. I tried following to this docs from metaplex https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/tree/main/getting-started-react-cra5 , but it doesn't work for me.
ERROR
process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:268288:18)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:502780:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:502174:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:502438:21)
    at ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:269113:20)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:502780:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:502174:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:502438:21)
    at ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:266539:14)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:502780:31)

Some one can help me, save me out.

You can post another question on what you'd like to accomplish and I'll try my best to help out.

yeah, I'm so appreciate

The package is depracated and not in active development.
Please switch to Umi and use the associated plugins

Metadata Program - @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata
Core Program - @metaplex-foundation/mpl-core
Bubblegum Program - @metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum
Candy Machine Program - @metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine


I just want to get metadata information from my own token.

check this out https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/fetch#fetch-by-mint
create a new question if you are new to UMI

yeah, I'm really new with UMI, let me try this out. ❤
